# How to sort column headers by date disregarding the first two non-date columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to sort my column headers by date disregarding the first two columns.

I've tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime
cols_as_date = [datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%m-%Y') for x in df.columns]
df = df[sorted(cols_as_data)]
```

**but it returned:**

```
ValueError: time data 'header1' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
```

**my.csv**

```
header1    header2    01-09-2020    02-09-2020   03-09-2020   04-09-2020   05-09-2020   06-09-2020   31-08-2020
```

**desired output:**

```
header1    header2   31-08-2020   01-09-2020    02-09-2020   03-09-2020   04-09-2020   05-09-2020   06-09-2020
```

Would someone be able to help with this? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  Split the header into two parts: non-dates and dates.

```
from datetime import datetime

headers = 'header1    header2    01-09-2020    02-09-2020   03-09-2020   04-09-2020   05-09-2020   06-09-2020   31-08-2020'
headers = headers.split()

prefix = headers[:2]
rest = headers[2:]

# convert to dates and sort
rest = sorted([datetime.strptime(r, '%d-%m-%Y') for r in rest])

# change date format
rest = [r.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') for r in rest]

headers = prefix + rest
print(headers)

['header1', 'header2', '31-08-2020', '01-09-2020', '02-09-2020', 
 '03-09-2020', '04-09-2020', '05-09-2020', '06-09-2020']
```

Comment: Hi jsmart, thank you for the answer. I've tried the above but received an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`for `headers = headers.split()`. Would you know how can I solve this? thanks

Comment: it actually worked without headers = headers.split() :) thanks!

Comment: Great!  I think your example started with a list.  Mine started with a string, and .split() turned in into a list.  You were already there :)